# Sequence diagram synchronous and asynchronous messages

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, uml, message, sequence-diagram

I am not quite sure that I am using **synchronous** and **asynchronous** messages correctly in the diagram I have built.When we talk about asynchrony, the sequence of actions is lost. Does this mean that I can remove an announcment even before I add information about it? Сorrect me if I'm wrong. Also I will be grateful for an explanation if there is something contradictory in my diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asynchronous message means that the sender doesn't wait for the response and continue its execution.  Looking at the incoming and outgoing message on each line separately,  we could imagine that:

- The user can send all the announcement information to the announcement creation page;
- The user could then without waiting continue very fast, and send a remove message to the announcement page.
- The announcement creation page could only then continue its execution and create the add.

However, the sequence diagram is not meant to be a specification of an algorithm.  Some use it for visual programming, but your question demonstrate it isn't.  In fact the sequence diagram represents a typical scenario.  And in the scenario you have modelled,  the order of the message is such that the announcement creation page is finished before the removal.

*Btw,  the two creation messages that create a new lifeline must be a dashed line with an open arrow head.  This is a special case of messages and in this case the open arrow has nothing to do with asynchronicity.*

Comment: sorry,that is, I should just point the dashed line back for each "asynchronous" message, right?

Comment: will the dashed line back be enough to show that I can only delete an already created announcment?

Comment: I seem to understand, do I just have to terminate each "thread" before starting a new one..

Comment: The 2ndmessage looks like it needs to be synchronous as the 3nd message would not make sense before the first being served.

Comment: @Smth_Unknown you may be interested in strict and seq combined fragments: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-strict

Comment: Honestly, I can't guess the added value for this. Aren't messgage meant to appear in  (strict) order downwards anyway?

Comment: @qwerty_so: Even if the second message `DisplayPage` would be synchroneous, it could not stop the user to send the third message `SetAnInfo` at any time after the first message. If we want to show that this cannot happen, the `AnCreationPage` would need to send a message to the user.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer Hmm. Does not convince me. The example in the UML spec uses synch messages. I will think a bit about this...